# Como deixar os valores no relatorio com o iReport(ou TIBCO) somente com 2 casas decimais

Tags: java, sql, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

Queria fazer com que meus valores em reais, ficassem apenas 2 casas decimais em meu relatório, mas não sei onde declarar isso.
Na minha aplicação eu declarei todos tipo floa[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina o atributo pattern para a tag textField:

```
    <textField pattern="###0.00">
        <reportElement x="437" y="462" width="100" height="20"/>
        <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{fieldFloat}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

Se estiver usando uma IDE, como iReport, nas propriedades do objeto vai ter esse atributo `pattern` com várias opções.

Comment: Estou usando a IDE sim, mas eu coloco isso onde? No XML?

Comment: Se puder olhar minha imagem que postei, pq não sei onde encaixar isso...

Comment: Opa, estive ausente. Na sua imagem você está destacando o `<staticText>` que é (provavelmente) o nome da coluna, no caso `Valor Parcela`. Você deve colocar o pattern no `textField`, que é o campo que receberá realmente o valor da parcela (e.g. 50.00).

Comment: Como você está usando o iReport, na aba de Design (na imagem está na de XML), clique em cima do campo que vai mostrar o valor, deve aparecer a tabela de propriedades do lado direito, daí é só procurar a propriedade Pattern. Ao clicar abre uma janela que inclusive tem várias sugestões de formato. Espero que você já tenha achado a resposta, nesse caso, publique aqui para ajudar a outras pessoas.